# app crashes while showing mapView in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios7, mkmapview

I've created a tabbed application and in that one tab is view controller with a map view. The other tab in the app works fine but when I try to switch to the tab with the mapView it crashes. I've currently set the mapView to show user's current location. Please let me know where I'm going wrong. below is the code for the view controller with map view.

SecondViewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

SecondViewcontroller.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController () 

 @end

@implementation SecondViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[_mapView setDelegate:self];
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
 }


 -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
  {
[_mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }


 @end
```

Image of crash report
[image]

Comment: Adding the crash report could be quite helpful... (Crash exception logged)

Comment: What does this have to do with Xcode IDE or android maps?

Comment: I'm sorry I added the map view tag wrongly… sorry for my mistake